# Easiest way to submit a form to ServletUnit using something like WebRequest in HttpUnit

Tags: java, http-unit

I would like to programmatically create a form with fields etc, however i have not been able to find a public factory etc to create a WebForm(class). Once this is done i would like to then submit the form and have my servlet do stuff with the form.

One approach i noticed the tests use is to create a PseudoServer which is a simple socket server. The tests then eventually make a request to some url which replies with some arbitrary html which includes a form. The problem with this is i cant register my own custom servlet to do stuff.

Im thus stuck between wanting a form but being unable to create one, if i wish to unit servletunit.

- Is there a way to submit forms to a servlet inside servlet unit ?
- Is there a way to combine parts of httpunit the form submitting stuff w/ servlet unit ?

Im guessing probably not because it(httpunit) wants to submit a form via socket and servletunit does not use sockets at all.

As per Andrey's suggestion and my past experimenting i have attempted to to call numerous methods on WebRequest to attempt to communicate the stuff that exists in a form being posted to a server.

- selectFile() - to pick the file to be uploaded
- setHeaderField() to set content type/charset/encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PostMethodWebRequest](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/PostMethodWebRequest.html) to send POST request to any HTTP URL:

```
WebRequest request = new PostMethodWebRequest(serverUrl);
```

And then just set form parameters directly in the request object:

```
request.setParameter('name', 'user1');
request.setParameter('password', '123456');
```

Comment: But i want that means i need a web server to return the "initial page". Why cant i just build the initial page in a simpler way...sorry im confused...atm, seems like a lot of stuffing about for something that should be simple. This page will thus return the page which is then submitted to servlet unit.. is that right ?

Comment: I was using something ver y similoar to what i have given but unfortunately it doesnt work if one attempts to submit a form with a file. Lots of headers on the server(inside servletunit) are missing like the charset etc.

Comment: multipart requests are slightly more complicated than an average form submit.

Comment: @mP, I'm confused either :) May be you can update your question with some code example that you've tried?